# Python Selenium: select option

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have to select an option from a dropdown menu, the HTML code is

```
<select id="formIdVeic" style="width: 250px; display: none;" class="combobox-f combo-f" comboname="formIdVeic">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="E">TARGA ESTERA </option>
    <option value="J">TARGA FILOBUS </option>
    <option value="L">TELAIO </option>
    <option value="TN" selected="selected">TARGA ITALIANA NUOVO FORMATO </option>
    <option value="TS">TARGA ITALIANA SPECIALE </option>
    <option value="TV">TARGA ITALIANA VECCHIO FORMATO </option>
    <option value="X">TARGA PROVA </option>
    <option value="Y">TARGA PROVVISORIA </option>
</select>
```

I want to select the "TV" option. The solution I've come to is

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
...
a=Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="formIdVeic"]'))
a.select_by_visible_text("TARGA ITALIANA VECCHIO FORMATO").click()
```

or

```
a.select_by_value("TV").click()
```

where browser is a web browser driver. Both the solutions return an exception:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: 
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have display "none" in the style definition

Comment: style="width: 250px; display: none;"

Comment: So I cannot select anything because it's not displayed?

Comment: That exactly what selenium saying: "the element not visible"

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now, it comes to my mind, when I inspect the dropdown menu, it doesn't redirect me to the select contruction, but to this:
`<span class="combo" style="width: 248px;">  <input type="text" class="combo-text validatebox-text" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" style="width: 230px;">  <span>  <span class="combo-arrow">  </span>  </span>  <input type="hidden" class="combo-value" name="formIdVeic" value="TN">  </span>`.
What can I do with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't select the non visible element in Selenium. 
The source for the visibility check -

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L577